# rainbow effect multiple users

Tags: jquery

```
$.getScript("http://xoxco.com/projects/code/rainbow/rainbow.js",function(){
 $('a[href="/u1"] strong').html(function(){
 $(this).rainbow({ 
colors: [
    '#FF0000',
    '#f26522',
    '#fff200',
    '#00a651',
    '#28abe2',
    '#2e3192',
    '#6868ff'
],
animate: true,
animateInterval: 100,
pad: false,
pauseLength: 100,
    });
  });
});
```

That is the script I have, is there a way to select multiple names ?

`('a[href="/u1"] strong','a[href="/u2"]')` sort of like that?

Came up with a small fix::

```
$.getScript("http://xoxco.com/projects/code/rainbow/rainbow.js",function(){
  var a = $('a[href="/u1"] strong,a[href="/u33"]');
   a.addClass('.rainbow');
 $('.rainbow').rainbow({ 
colors: [
    '#FF0000',
    '#f26522',
    '#fff200',
    '#00a651',
    '#28abe2',
    '#2e3192',
    '#6868ff'
],
animate: true,
animateInterval: 100,
pad: false,
pauseLength: 100,
});
});
```

Though it is not adding the the actual rainbow effect...any suggestions. I'll make a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LUdrF/

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ["starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
$('a[href^="/u"] strong').html(function(){
```

And replace

```
a.addClass('.rainbow');
```

with

```
a.addClass('rainbow');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/mdtS3/)

Comment: updated first post with a fix, need a little more help though

Comment: oh yeah I fixed it never updated the fiddle grrr. but what is the console.log(a)?

Comment: When debugging, I used console.log to see that there was no problem in your jQuery collection. I forgot to remove it once I had the rainbow working.

Answer (score 1):

This should work;

```
$('a[href="/u1"] strong, a[href="/u2"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: works, but making the a only destroys the html and shows it in a rainbow lol. I may just have to make it so it adds a class

Comment: I've updated first post with a fix, need little more help though